# Slot machine segfault: what can we determine?

Tags: linux, hardware, physical

We walked into a casino and saw this near the entrance. I don't have a specific question, but is there anything that would be interesting to share and explain from the image?

[image: Casino slot machine segfault]

Comment: Well, I just learned that Bose apparently makes slot machines. :/

Comment: @SteveS Nope, they just specialise in small speakers, which this slot machine just happens to use. The manufacturer of this slot machine is [WMS](http://www.wms.com/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: it dropped you to a root shell!  too bad you didn't have a keyboard attached...

Comment: I tried pressing buttons on the machine, hoping you could somehow type with them, but no luck

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few observations:

- It's a 32-bit Linux OS. Difficult to tell which distro - might be something custom.
- They're running the latest version of Bash shell.
- It contains an NVRAM device, such as an onboard EEPROM, which failed to initialise due to corruption. These are often used as tamper-proof storage modules that contain the game code.
- It's on the network (IPv4 address is 10.254.0.10) and an NTP client is running.
- No idea what `rds_doNSQuery` or `RDSU_QUERY_NOWAIT` mean.
- The `eip` and `esp` registers weren't trashed by the crash, so I'd guess the crash was a forced segfault due to integrity checking failure, rather than a buffer overflow.

All in all, a rather interesting crash. Nice catch!

Comment: looks like the network cable has fallen out and it requires network before proceeding.  I imagine a lot of modern gaming machines work like that nowadays.

Comment: If that was the case, eth0 probably wouldn't have a `10.x.x.x` address; it'd probably mark itself as down.

Comment: Another observation; it's on a 6-bit (64 machine) subnet.